# POST request with Volley with headers and body (java, android studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, http-post, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST request with `Volley` in Android Studio. However, I would like to set some headers and a body. How can I do this?
In this case, the `headers` are `id` and `key`. Where should I add the body? I have tried to follow the numerous questions about these that are written in StackOverflow. However, it still seems like the headers and the body is not properly sent.

```
        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = "https://url.of.the.server";
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            jsonBody.put("id", "oneapp.app.com");
            jsonBody.put("key", "fgs7902nskagdjs");
            final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    params.put("id", "oneapp.app.com");
                    params.put("key", "fgs7902nskagdjs");

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {
                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                        // can get more details such as response.headers
                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            };
            Log.d("string", stringRequest.toString());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi, what is the response you are receiving for the request?

Comment: This is the response:```2021-05-22 13:17:00.614 22209-22982/com.example.chattutorial E/Volley: [43149] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://url.of.the.server
2021-05-22 13:17:00.617 22209-22209/com.example.chattutorial E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ClientError
2021-05-22 13:17:00.666 22209-22994/com.example.chattutorial E/Volley: [43156] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://url.of.the.server
2021-05-22 13:17:00.667 22209-22209/com.example.chattutorial E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ClientError```

Comment: @Vinujan.S do you believe the headers are in the right place?

Comment: Seems you are getting 400 error code. this means your headers and body are wrong. you could understand more by enabling debug logging for volley.

with the debug logging, you can observe the actual request structure, then you could compare with actual request and find the issue.

Comment: By looking at your code, you are sending the same thing for the body and header.

what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly setting the headers, you could try this

```
 try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "https://url.of.the.server";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                     // request body goes here
                     JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                     jsonBody.put("attribute1", "value1");
                     String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
                    return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("id", "oneapp.app.com");
                params.put("key", "fgs7902nskagdjs");

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };
        Log.d("string", stringRequest.toString());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For example, if request body is

```
{
  name: "name1",
  email: "email1"
}
```

`getBody` method would be

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
 JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
 jsonBody.put("name", "name1");
 jsonBody.put("email", "email1");
 String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
 return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
}
```